# Tags system - searching with 'some tags' AND without 'other tags'

Tags: php, mysql, search, tags

I was trying to do this like that:

Two inputs:

1."search questions with tags:"
 2."and without tags"

```
TABLE: questions (
-id,
-url,
 .
 .
 .
-other data
)

TABLE: tags (
-id,
-tag
)

TABLE: tags_and_questions (
-id,
-question_id,
-tag_id
)

SELECT `question_id` FROM `tags_and_questions` WHERE `tag_id` IN ($ok_tags_id) AND `tag_id` NOT IN ($no_tags_id)
```

Data example in table tags_and_questions:

```
question_id   tag_id
   1            1
   1            2
   1            3
```

When $no_tags_id = 3, result of fetching tags_and_questions is array ([0] => 1, [1] => 1)

Is this possible with this tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is using aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT `question_id`
FROM `tags_and_questions`
GROUP BY question_id
HAVING sum(`tag_id` IN ($ok_tags_id)) > 0 and
       sum(`tag_id` NOT IN ($no_tags_id)) = 0;
```

This will return questions that have one or more tags from the "ok" tags and none of the "no" tags.

Of course, this structure assumes that you are actually creating the SQL as a string to pass it in.  Otherwise, the "lists" will be treated as single values.

EDIT:

If the query is returning no rows, then I suspect it is because your list is going in as a single string.  In MySQL, you can do:

```
SELECT `question_id`
FROM `tags_and_questions`
GROUP BY question_id
HAVING sum(find_in_set(`tag_id`, $ok_tags_id) > 0) > 0 and
       sum(find_in_set(`tag_id`, $no_tags_id) > 0) = 0;
```